# How to lookup a value that depends on more than 1 column (Excel)?

Tags: excel

I have two sheets in my workbook. one is for unique clients, and the other is a combined table with clients and other details.

Say in Sheet A:

```
ID  |  Name  |  Addr
1   |  Peter |  10a...
2   |  Aaron |  18...
.   |    .   |   .
.   |    .   |   .
```

In Sheet B:

```
ID  |  Name  |  Addr
    |  Peter |  10a...
    |  Peter |  10a...
    |  Aaron |  18...
    |  Aaron |  18...
```

I want to set the ID in sheet B according to the client details. Say, if the content of column "Name" and "Addr" in sheet B equals to the content in "Name" and "Addr" in sheet A, then put the value of "ID" sheet A into sheet B.

So, sheet B should be like this:

```
ID  |  Name  |  Addr
1   |  Peter |  10a...
1   |  Peter |  10a...
2   |  Aaron |  18...
2   |  Aaron |  18...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use VLOOKUP with Concatenate:**

In Sheet 1, create a unique Concatenated Key for each row by concatenating Name and Address.  `&` is the concatenation operator. Formula: `=B2&C2`

Now in Sheet 2, use VLOOKUP using the Concatenated Key:

```
  = VLOOKUP(B2&C2, Sheet1!$A$2$:$D$500,2,FALSE)
```

Some important points here:

- you're looking up the matching key (B2&C2)
- you're requiring an EXACT match (FALSE),
- and you'll pick up ID (column 2).
- Don't forget to ANCHOR the reference table (use the $).  In the above example, I've assumed 500 unique clients in Sheet 1.  Fill in as desired.

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome.  Which sheet is called what?   If Sheet 1 is called Client, then this looks fine to me.  If Sheet 2 is called Client, then since your vlookup is on Sheet 2, you want to reference Sheet 1.  (Also, a bit puzzled, why so many concatenated columns?)

Comment: @KyleXie: If you found the answer helpful, please upvote it.  If it solves your problem, please select it as the correct answer (check box beside it).  Thanks!

Comment: It it very powerful. Thank you.